# Output Error for Matrix in Python?

Tags: function, python-3.x, join, matrix, format

I am trying to create a function that outputs a matrix that contains each item in a list on a separate line with lines in between. The only output I'm getting is quotations (''). I do not understand why. I think I set it all up correctly to output what is needed but there has to be something missing?

I included examples below my code.

```
def show_table(table):
 table=[]
 s=[[str(e) for e in row] for row in table]
 lens= [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
 fmt= '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
 table= [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
 return '\n'.join(table) 

show_table([['A','BB'],['C','DD']])
```

output:

'|  A   |   BB  |\n|    C   |   DD  |\n'

print(show_table([['A','BB'],['C','DD']]))
output:

|   A   |   BB  |
|   C   |   DD  |

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the second line where you are initialising your list to an empty list. Instead try:

```
if table is None:
    table = []
```

Perhaps a better way to accomplish this could be:

```
def show_table(table):
    if table is None:
        table = []
    data = ""
    for row in table:
        for val in row:
            data += "| " + val + " "
        data += "|\n"
    return data.strip("\n")

print show_table([['a','bb'],['c','dd']])
```

Output:

```
| a | bb |
| c | dd |
```

Comment: How would I put the line between? Your solution did fix the output problem!

Comment: I've updated the answer, though I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish I hope this gives you a general idea to build off of.

Comment: I need that output put with a line on both sides, spaces in between | a | bb |

Comment: I'm receiving the error: list  cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: I'm receiving the error: list  cannot be interpreted as an integer. There generally aren't multiple items in each list. It's a list of lists with one item in it. Ex: show_table([['a'],['b'],['c']])

Comment: As you can see here: https://repl.it/G3Gg/0 - It does work in python 3.5.2 and I tested it locally in  2.7.13. Unsure what's causing your issue, what python version are you running?